# How to avoid obsolete warning when defining a compatibility alias?

Tags: elisp

Currently, I have this code:

```cl
(defalias 'hydra-set-transient-map
    (if (fboundp 'set-transient-map)
        'set-transient-map
      (lambda (map keep-pred &optional on-exit)
        (set-temporary-overlay-map map (hydra--pred on-exit)))))
```

It uses the newer `set-transient-map` that obsoletes `set-temporary-overlay-map` when it's
available, however I still want the package to work for Emacs versions that don't have
`set-transient-map`. And I'm getting this warning when byte compiling:

> set-temporary-overlay-map is an obsolete function (as of 24.4);
>   use set-transient-map instead.

What's the proper procedure to avoid the warning in this case, without
ignoring a whole class of warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your obsolete code with a [`with-no-warnings`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/with-no-warnings) form.

```
(defalias 'hydra-set-transient-map
  (if (fboundp 'set-transient-map)
      'set-transient-map
    (with-no-warnings
      (lambda (map keep-pred &optional on-exit)
        (set-temporary-overlay-map map (hydra--pred on-exit))))))
```

From the docstring:

> (with-no-warnings &rest BODY)
>   Like `progn`, but prevents compiler warnings in the body.

Comment: That's not bad. I was thinking of something along the lines that
the branch with `set-temporary-overlay-map` never gets called in appropriate Emacs.
So with something like `eval-when-compile` maybe it could be possible to avoid the warning.

Comment: @abo-abo I think just wrapping the entire `if` inside an `eval-when-compile` should also work here, but `with-no-warnings` is equally effective. It is also more expressive about your intentions and will work in more situations.