# Best way to support obsolete variables

Tags: variables, version-support

Emacs 25.1 obsoletes a variable `isearch-word` and recommends to use the new `isearch-regexp-function` instead.  Because Emacs 24 does not have the new variable, I can't just replace it like:

```
(if isearch-regexp-function
```

What's the best way to support both Emacs 24 and Emacs 25?

I don't want to just suppress the warning with `with-no-warnings`, which is already answered here: "[How to avoid obsolete warning when defining a compatibility alias?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9802)"

Answer (score 3):

Use `boundp` to test for the variable's existence:

> `(boundp SYMBOL)`
>
> Return `t` if SYMBOL's value is not void.
>   Note that if `lexical-binding` is in effect, this refers to the
>   global value outside of any lexical scope.

So:

```
(if (boundp 'isearch-regexp-function)
    (do-the-new-thing)
  (do-the-old-thing))
```

Comment: doesn't the bytecompiler warn you still if you have `isearch-word` in the else form?